# Android AlarmManager started with BOOT_COMPLETED then interacted with via app

Tags: android, alarmmanager, boot, android-context

I have an app that has an alarm registered (AlarmManager) to be started when the phone boots using BOOT_COMPLETED in manifest.  But when the user launches the app I want to allow the user to see that it is running and also allow the user to optionally turn off and on the Alarm manually.

I was thinking of storing a shared preference for the alarm state, e.g. 'running' or 'paused'.  The thing I am struggling to understand is the inter-operability of the Context that starts the AlarmManager on boot, and the more ordinary context that is present when the user is running the app.  Is there any best practices around handling interaction between system enabled alarms vs. user enabled alarms???

Also is there a way to view the running Alarms for a given app?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no API to list registered alarms. The Context you use doesn't matter. All you need to cancel an alarm is to create an equivalent `PendingIntent` to the one you used to register the alarm -- use the same request code, flags and Intent.